# Get current user Async in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

When I use **get_current_user(**) I need to check few things in **Redis** (use **tornado-redis**) asynchronously.

I am doing the following:

```
def authenticated_async(method):

    @gen.coroutine
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._auto_finish = False
        self.current_user = yield gen.Task(self.get_current_user_async)
        if not self.current_user:
            self.redirect(self.reverse_url('login'))
        else:
            result = method(self, *args, **kwargs) # updates
            if result is not None:
                yield result
    return wrapper

class BaseClass():

    @gen.coroutine
    def get_current_user_async(self,):

        auth_cookie = self.get_secure_cookie('user') # cfae7a25-2b8b-46a6-b5c4-0083a114c40e
        user_id = yield gen.Task(c.hget, 'auths', auth_cookie) # 16
        print(123, user_id)
        return auth_cookie if auth_cookie else None
```

For example, I want to use **authenticated_async** decorator:

```
class IndexPageHandler(BaseClass, RequestHandler):

    @authenticated_async
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")
```

But I have in console only **123**.

Whats wrong? How to fix that?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I have updated the code with `yield result`.

In **auth_cookie** I have `cfae7a25-2b8b-46a6-b5c4-0083a114c40e`.

Then I go to terminal:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hget auths cfae7a25-2b8b-46a6-b5c4-0083a114c40e
"16"
```

So,

```
user_id = yield gen.Task(c.hget, 'auths', auth_cookie)
print(123, user_id)
```

Must return

```
123 16
```

But it returns one 123

**UPDATE 1**

With

```
class IndexPageHandler(BaseClass, RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        print('cookie', self.get_secure_cookie('user'))
        user_async = yield self.get_current_user_async()
        print('user_async', user_async)
        print('current user', self.current_user)
        self.render("index.html",)
```

In console I have:

```
cookie b'cfae7a25-2b8b-46a6-b5c4-0083a114c40e'
123 
user_async b'cfae7a25-2b8b-46a6-b5c4-0083a114c40e'
current user None
```

Comment: If the wrapped method is itself a coroutine, you must yield it when calling it from `authenticated_async`'s wrapper (`result = method(*args, **kwargs); if result is not None: yield result`). That doesn't apply to this `IndexPageHandler`, though. If you're getting to the print statement it looks like all the async stuff is working and you're just getting an empty result from `c.hget` (whatever that is). If that's not it can you be more clear about what exactly you're expecting and what you're seeing instead?

Comment: Does it work without the decorator? What if you just call `get_secure_cookie` and `c.hget` (or `get_current_user_async`) in `handler.get` directly?

Comment: You need to wrap get() in `@gen.coroutine` and use `yield` when calling `get_current_user_async()`.

Comment: @BenDarnell sorry for my mistake, I have fixed it on update 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_secure_cookie()` returns a byte string; since the cookie printed out with a `b'` prefix you must be on Python 3. On Python 3, `tornado-redis` appears to expect unicode strings instead of byte strings; any input that is not a unicode string will be converted to one with the `str()` function. This adds the `b'` prefix seen above, so you are querying for `b'cfae7a25-2b8b-46a6-b5c4-0083a114c40e'`, not `cfae7a25-2b8b-46a6-b5c4-0083a114c40e`

The solution is to convert the cookie to a `str` before sending it to redis: `auth_cookie = tornado.escape.native_str(auth_cookie)`

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the doc string of gen.Task:

> Takes a function (and optional additional arguments) and runs it with
>       those arguments plus a `callback` keyword argument.

Does c.hget accept a callback argument? If not, the callback will throw an exception, the future won't be set a result, hence the print statement doesn't print the user id.

Comment: I use examples from here - https://github.com/leporo/tornado-redis#usage And expressions like `bar = yield tornado.gen.Task(c.get, 'bar')` nicely works

Answer (score 0):

The answer is back in your wrapper coroutine.

```
        if result is not None:
            yield result
```

You don't want to yield result, but to "return" it from the coroutine. However, since Python doesn't let you use a non-empty return from a generator, you need to raise it as a wrapped exception that Tornado can unwrap, and pass the result on to the caller (**get_current_user**)

```
if result is not None:
    raise gen.Return(result)
```

Having done that, you should find it works.